What's the equivalent of ConfigureAppConfiguration function in .Net 6 for .Net 8
currently i am using WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder->ConfigureAppConfiguration in .Net 6 to add ConfigurationSource. Now, i am doing upgrade to .Net 8 and will be using WebApplication.CreateBuilder (.Net 8) to replace WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder (.Net 6) but I can't find this ConfigureAppConfiguration function in WebApplication.CreateBuilder (.Net 8).
May I know what's the equivalent function in WebApplication.CreateBuilder (.Net 8) to perform the same funciton as ConfigureAppConfiguration in .Net 6 ?
Purpose: I am adding ConfigurationSource to IConfigurationBuilder for AWS secret manager. The functionality is similar to what's described in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/how-to-load-net-configuration-from-aws-secrets-manager/
Appreciate any advice
Thanks
Matthew
I have tried adding the ConfigurationSource to the IConfigurationBuilder in .Net 8 the similar way i did in .Net 6 but without the equivalent ConfigureAppConfiguration (.Net 6) function. But the content retrieved from the Secret Manager in AWS is empty. I want to make it work like ConfigureAppConfiguration but for .Net 8
UPDATE1
i have this extension

public static IConfigurationBuilder UseAmazonSecretManagerConfiguraton(this IConfigurationBuilder config, Action action)
{
if (action == null)
{
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
}
// new instance
var opts = new AWSProviderOptions();
        // invoke delegate
        action(opts);

        var configurationSource = (new AmazonKMSConfigurationSource
        {
            SecretName = opts.SecretName
        });

        config.Add(configurationSource);
        return config;
    }



Not sure how you are using ConfigureAppConfiguration now. Maybe, if you show the code that is not working in .NET 6, we can help you better.
You say that you try to add ConfigurationSource to IConfigurationBuilder for AWS secret manager. Generally, you add options like this:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());


Additionally, you can add SecretsManager NuGET package and use it in your application like this:
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSecretsManager>();

These APIs give you access to full functionality of Secrets Manager, including for configuration purposes
UPDATE 1: I followed the tutorial that you linked and ReSharper recommended to change the code from step 4.2
builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(((_, configurationBuilder) =>
{
    configurationBuilder.AddAmazonSecretsManager("<your region>", "<secret name>");
}));

to
builder.Configuration.AddAmazonSecretsManager("<your region>", "<secret name>");

Which is how I retrieved credentials in ASP.NET 7 as well (and maybe 6). For me the bigger problem with the blog is that I don't see how it retrieves credentials to get to AWS in the first place - which is where my GetAWSOptions(). But I am going to assume that you figured this out on your own, and that it didn't change.
UPDATE 2: I am going to rework that blog post to make it work. Note, that I am using this in non-default AWS profile. I am only going to put AWS-related code
Program.cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSecretsManager>();
builder.AddAmazonSecretsManager("<secret name>");
...
builder.Services.Configure<MyApiCredentials>(builder.Configuration);


AddAmazonSecretsManager is now an extension method on Builder, rather than on configuration. This is where we get profile name and region name from appsettings.json. After this we don't need to put region in the code any more.
public static void AddAmazonSecretsManager(this WebApplicationBuilder builder, string secretName)
{
    AWSOptions? options = builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
    builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(options);

    AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationSource configurationSource = new(options, secretName);
    IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = builder.Configuration;
    configurationBuilder.Add(configurationSource);
}

appsettings.json is expected to have the following section:
"AWS": {
  "Profile": "profilename",
  "Region": "us-east-1"
}

If "profilename" is assured to be "default", then you can probably simplify some of the intializations
AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationSource
public class AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationSource(AWSOptions options, string secretName) 
    : IConfigurationSource
{
    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationProvider(options, secretName);
    }
}

AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationProvider
public class AmazonSecretsManagerConfigurationProvider(AWSOptions options, string secretName) : ConfigurationProvider
{
    public override  void Load()
    {
        string secret =  GetSecretAsync().Result;
        Data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(secret)!;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetSecretAsync()
    {
        GetSecretValueRequest request = new()
        {
            SecretId = secretName,
            VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT" // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified.
        };

        IAmazonSecretsManager? client = options.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonSecretsManager>();
        GetSecretValueResponse? response = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request);

        string secretString;
        if (response.SecretString != null)
        {
            secretString = response.SecretString;
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryStream? memoryStream = response.SecretBinary;
            StreamReader reader = new(memoryStream);
            secretString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(await reader.ReadToEndAsync()));
        }

        return secretString;
    }
}


the .net 6 version is working, you may refer to the URL just edited. Now need to migrate the feature to .net 8. I will check your answer

in the context of the above url mentioned, how do i change the following function block using WebApplication.CreateBuilder:

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration(((_, configurationBuilder) =>
{
configurationBuilder.AddAmazonSecretsManager("", "");
}));


I understand what you are asking; I suppose, it's a different way to get credentials from Secrets Manager. The one in the blog seems interesting though - let me play with that one later today

Thanks Felix, i have similar extension see Update1... this is how it's call from program.cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
builder.Configuration.UseAmazonSecretManagerConfiguraton(config =>
{
config.SecretName = $"parent/childpath";
})

is the AddDefaultAWSOptions correctly used or the mapping for this is lost ?

note AmazonKMSConfigurationSource has been tested working in .net 6, i can reuse it in .net 8... tested in .net 8 it can retrieve the connectionstring value from secret manager...
now the issue may relate to the use of builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions()); and it may not map correctly to builder.Configuration.UseAmazonSecretManagerConfiguraton... pls advise on this mapping

First, I don't think there were any major changes between .net 6 and .net 8. What changed, if I am not mistaken, was AWS packages - from AWS.xxx to AWSSDK.xxx. The APIs changed, although I found the transition to be quite straightforward. Second, you are confusing two operations: builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions()) authenticates to AWS (similar to user profile), while KMS or Secrets Manager stores some keys or credentials to other services (like DynamoDB or relational database). the first never wipes out the second

thanks for your explanation... so now the issue is not AddDefaultAWSOptions and also not builder.Configuration.UseAmazonSecretManagerConfiguraton... this is the calling project... now i am checking the called project submodule, may be there's a missing link here

@MatthewKok - I reworked the blog post to work with options in appsettings.json

if the calling project A is using .net 8 and the called project library B is using .net 6... A is calling B to access some library functions or the A's connectionstring is passed to B for data layer operation, will there be a problem ?

No idea... I have some code where library B is using old .NET Framework. But I would be very nervous of having such mismatch

thanks for the blog rework, it will help other readers... now i am testing on submodules B and may try changing to .net 8 because the connectionstring value in B is empty but there's a value in calling project A

i have approved your answer since you have confirmed the builder configuration in .net 8 can be used to replace ConfigureAppConfiguration in .net 6 and this is the scope of my initial question. Thank you
